# How to group a list of tuples based on similar fields and then keep the maximum based on another field? (without using Pandas)

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have list of tuples like

```
bottles = [(1234, 'ICED', 'MOC12', 3), (1234, 'ICED', 'MOC12', 2), (3456, 'HOT', 'CAR23', 1), (3456, 'HOT', 'YUP23', 2)]
```

I want the tuple corresponding to the max of the last field for each groups. The groups are defined by the first three values.

Output:

```
result = [(1234, 'ICED', 'MOC12', 3),(3456, 'HOT', 'CAR23', 1),(3456, 'HOT','YUP23', 2)]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You say "something like this" without any explanation. Please give a clear, concise explanation of the sort order and groupings. Also, you seem to give two outputs for one input. Which of those is the one you really want?

Comment: Edited the post. That's the output I am looking for @RoryDaulton

Comment: Are you looking at groups as defined by having their first three elements common, and then finding the maximum of each such group? A little more verbosity would help your case greatly

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for "looking at groups as defined by having their first three elements common, and then finding the maximum of each such group" @IzaakvanDongen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your comment, this should work:

```
from itertools import groupby

bottles = [(1234, 'ICED', 'MOC12', 3), (1234, 'ICED', 'MOC12', 2), (3456, 'HOT', 'CAR23', 1), (3456, 'HOT', 'YUP23', 2)]
print([max(group) for key, group in groupby(sorted(bottles), lambda a: a[:3])])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bottles = [(1234, 'ICED', 'MOC12', 3), (1234, 'ICED', 'MOC12', 2), (3456, 'HOT', 'CAR23', 1), (3456, 'HOT', 'YUP23', 2)]

sorted(bottles, key= lambda x: x[:3])
>>> [(1234, 'ICED', 'MOC12', 3),
 (1234, 'ICED', 'MOC12', 2),
 (3456, 'HOT', 'CAR23', 1),
 (3456, 'HOT', 'YUP23', 2)]
```

you can also obtain directly the max using `max` instead of `sorted`.

Comment: NB `len(result) == 3`